# Accessing value of select_tag in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am having trouble accessing a value of select_tag in my controller. I have the following select_tag in my view:

```
= select_tag "yessir", options_for_select([ ["No Teardown Time","0"],["15 Minutes", "15"], ["30 Minutes", "30"], ["45 Minutes", "45"], ["60 Minutes", "60"], ["75 Minutes", "75"], ["90 Minutes","90"], ["105 Minutes", "105"],["120 Minutes","120"]], @event.teardown_time), {:prompt => 'Teardown Time'}
```

And I try to access it in my controller like such:

```
a = params["yessir"]
```

I have also tried

```
a = params[:yessir]
```

But in either case I keep on getting undefined local variable or method `params' for #. Any suggestions? Cheers~

On another note, how would I obtain the value if the select_tag had the following name:

```
= select_tag 'event[teardown_time]'
```

I tried params['event[teardown_time'], but it did not work - no error but value is not being obtained. Cheers~

Comment: Can you post the full controller code please.

Comment: Are you definitely passing the selected value to controller?

Comment: pretty large file - any specific part of the file? And Passing the value how? Is there something I need to add to the controller so it recognizes the value?

Comment: yes are you using scaffolds? if so there is record_params at the bottom you need to add the value you are taking in from the form.

Comment: Ahhh wow ... ok sorry about this but I am trying to access it in the model. My bad ... same idea though?

Comment: I would pass it to a controller method and from there call the model function with the value as a parameter

Comment: I was able to get it registering in my controller within the update method. How would I then call it in my model?

Comment: Can you see the value of `yessir` getting passed in the terminal where rails server is running?

Comment: yea that's where I'm seeing it, used a puts method

Comment: If you're using a form_for then you need to access the :yessir attribute inside the nested form object.  If your form_for object is say something like @event then you would access the param by doing:   a = params[:event][:yessir]

Comment: ok, for some reason the select_tag needs a name of event[teardown_time] ... so would a = params[:event][:teardown_time] work - Just tested it, params[:event][:teardown_time] worked, duh! Still getting used to ruby syntax

Comment: So how could I then access that variable in my model

Comment: you can pass it as a parameter to a function where you would like to use it function(yessir)